# How do I use helpers in rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, helper

Can I use helper methods in rake?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, you can. You simply need to require the helper file and then include that helper inside your rake file (which actually a helper is a mixin that we can include).

For example, here I have an **application_helper** file inside **app/helpers** directory that contains this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def hi
    "hi"
  end
end
```

so here is my rake file's content:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/application_helper"
include ApplicationHelper

namespace :help do
  task :hi do
    puts hi
  end
end
```

and here is the result on my Terminal:

```
god:helper-in-rake arie$ rake help:hi 
hi
```

Comment: Beware, by using `include` within rake, you inadvertently pollute the scope of `Object`, which succumbs all subsequently imported rake tasks to sharing the same methods.

Comment: What do you mean by subsequently imported rake tasks? As in rake tasks from other .rake files would also have access to the ApplicationHelper methods?

Comment: It's been said and said, but it can't be said enough... you *really* shouldn't do this, especially in a Rails app (which use Rake extensively). It messes with the global `Object`, which can have far-reaching effects that can be extremely hard to track down. Just lost two hours to this...

Answer (score 20):

As lfender6445 mentioned, using `include ApplicationHelper`, as in Arie's answer, is going to pollute the top-level scope containing your tasks.

Here's an alternative solution that avoids that unsafe side-effect.

First, we should **not** put our task helpers in `app/helpers`. To quote from ["Where Do I Put My Code?"](http://codefol.io/posts/Where-Do-I-Put-My-Code) at codefol.io:

> Rails “helpers” are very specifically view helpers. They’re automatically included in views, but not in controllers or models. That’s on purpose.

Since `app/helpers` is intended for view helpers, and Rake tasks are not views, we should put our task helpers somewhere else. I recommend `lib/task_helpers`.

In `lib/task_helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def self.hi
    "hi"
  end
end
```

In your `Rakefile` or a `.rake` file in `lib/tasks`:

```
require 'task_helpers/application_helper'

namespace :help do
  task :hi do
    puts ApplicationHelper.hi
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if the question was originally asking about including view helpers in rake tasks, or just "helper methods" for Rake tasks. But it's not ideal to share a helper file across both views and tasks. Instead, take the helpers you want to use in *both* views and tasks, and move them to a separate dependency that's included both in a view helper, and in a task helper.

Comment: This solved it for me -- if you want to pass arguments to the helper method, you will be unable to do it unless you sort the scope out as you have done

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a good idea to call it `application_helper.rb` as it might cause confusion. Maybe just `lib/task_helpers.rb` would be better.