# Rails and Rake task - How to call a Rails method inside a custom class defined in a rake task file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have the following code in `"Rails Root"/lib/tasks/example.rake`:

```
task :example_task => :environment do
  e = Example.new
  e.example_method
end

class Example
  def example_method
    select_tag 'Example'
  end
end
```

When I call `e.example_method` in the rake task, I get the error `"undefined method 'select_tag' for #<Example:0x39f58b0>"`.

`select_tag` is a Rails method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

How do I make the `select_tag` call work?

Comment: You just need to require the helpers you need. Please check this [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450112/how-do-i-use-helpers-in-rake

Comment: `select_tag` is one of the helpers methods in `ActionView` Why would your Rake Task calling any method that is view related? Just curious

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the helper the method you're trying to use. In the case of `select_tag`, you'll need to require `ActionView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

Access helper methods via the helper variable:

```
helper.content_tag :li, "Helola" 
=> "<li>Helola</li>"
```

or require the desired helpers

```
require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/helpers/some_helper.rb"
include SomeHelper
```